# Por qué NetBeans no me muestra las opciones para empaquetar?

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema con mi netbeans que cuando quiero darle a las opciones de empaquetamiento no me deja se me queda en blanco[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué opción de empaquetamiento tienes que cambiar?

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que la categoría de donde seleccionaste para crear la aplicación java es `Java with Maven` por eso vez una pequeña `m` sobre el logo de la taza en los proyectos, para un proyecto digamos de tipo normal crea el proyecto java utilizando la categoría `Java with ant` para tener las opciones que mencionas, pero idealmente el estándar es utilizar `maven` por el manejo de las dependencias y la facilidad de versionamiento en git, para construir un proyecto `maven` : `clic derecho sobre el proyecto` > `clean and build` > el jar estara en una carpeta llamada `\target` dentro de tu proyecto.